# Setting a particular chrome driver setting/option

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options

I need to uncheck "Ask where to save each file before downloading" `Chrome` setting via `selenium`:

[image]

I don't even know where to start since the [documentation page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) doesn't contain the list of all available options. And, I haven't found the appropriate setting among `chrome://flags/`.

As far as I understand, I need to instantiate `Chrome Options` or `Desired Capabilities`, set a particular option/capability and pass the `Chrome Options` or `Desired Capabilities` instance to the `ChromeDriver` constructor.

Note that for Firefox the situation is different, there is an [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) page where you can easily find a setting and set it via `Firefox Profile`. Pretty straightforward.

---

I'm using python bindings, but it is not a requirement, the question is more or less generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by inspecting the *element source* of this particular Chrome Setting:
[image]

The inspected HTML for it:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <span class="controlled-setting-with-label">
      <input id="prompt-for-download" type="checkbox" pref="download.prompt_for_download" metric="Options_AskForSaveLocation">
      <span>
        <label for="prompt-for-download" i18n-content="downloadLocationAskForSaveLocation">Ask where to save each file before downloading</label>
        <span class="bubble-button controlled-setting-indicator" pref="download.prompt_for_download">
        <div tabindex="0" role="button"></div></span>
      </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

As you can see, `input` element has `pref="download.prompt_for_download"` attribute. Eureka!

---

Now we can set the option, example using Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.prompt_for_download': False}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
```